# DHIS 2 analytics engine says it is in maintenance mode

Tags: dhis2

In DHIS 2, whenever i run the the data visualizer or pivot table favorites I am getting this error:

```
"Code 503 ,Status Service unavailable".

"Analytics engine is in maintenance mode, try again."
```

What does this mean and how can i correct this?

Answer (score 1):

This means that someone has put the DHIS 2 analytics engine in maintenance mode. This is useful when you need to do maintenance on the database server as load will decrease.

To disable the maintenance mode you can go to:

```
Apps > Settings > General
```

and uncheck the *Put analytics in maintenance mode* checkbox. Your favorites should now render normally again.